# Unable to create new tag (material science)

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags

I tried to create a new tag called *material science*, but the server states that this is a new tag and cannot be created at remote mobile site. I want to add this tag because I feel it would be helpful for the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Tags on Chem.SE are generally not unilaterally created by one person. If you want to make a new tag, the proper method would be to submit a proposal on meta.
2. Since your post doesn't contain any rationale for why such a post might prove "quite helpful", I am interpreting this post as solely asking for help on how to create a tag.
3. Creating a tag on mobile is disallowed for the reasons discussed here: [Why can't I create a new tag in Mobile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109063/why-cant-i-create-a-new-tag-in-mobile) This is intended behaviour of the system, hence [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).
4. If you wish to propose such a new tag please make a new meta post and the community will judge it based on its merits. However, I believe that such a proposal might not be very well-received, considering that the tag [materials](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) already exists.

Comment: ‘Tags on Chem.SE are generally not unilaterally created by one person’ — Hmmmmmmm. I know we generally do discuss tags on meta, but the Stack Exchange intended way is allowing everybody with more than 300 rep to create a tag if it is needed. I know this can result in more work for those cleaning up afterwards, but that again is more of a [tag:status-bydesign] thing.

Comment: @Jan Yes, you are right, it does contradict the SE model. From the low rep requirement, tag creation is clearly not something that they attach a lot of importance to, either. Personally, I think it is better to establish consensus. However, as always this is open to discussion.

Comment: I think I've said that often before: If you can find a critical amount of questions to support the tag, go ahead and create it, write a tag wiki and usage. It is by far easier to clean up tags that have not been used than retroactively introduce tags that could have been. Just see the functional groups tags, starting more than a year ago, still have not finished.

Comment: Also note, that I already proposed the change: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/393/4945

Comment: @Martin-マーチン You're the one who does the tag cleanup, so you'd know better on this, but on the few occasions where I've taken a look at newly introduced tags, they're generally single question tags that somebody simply introduced for their own question: no tag wiki, no usage guidance. If we want to let people make their own tags, then let's state it clearly, somewhere (this isn't really the place for it, I guess). In the meantime, there are enough tags that need wiki and usage added. And oops, I didn't see that meta post.